# Flutter Firestore transaction what this lines do?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I saw sample `Firestore` transaction code from flutter pub.
It looks like this.

```
final DocumentReference postRef = Firestore.instance.document('posts/123');
    Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
      DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await tx.get(postRef);
      if (postSnapshot.exists) {
        await tx.update(postRef, <String, dynamic>{'likesCount': postSnapshot.data['likesCount'] + 1});
      }
    });
```

I would like to know what this lines do.

```
DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await tx.get(postRef);
if (postSnapshot.exists)
```

Is this checking that document already exist or taking some transaction processes?

Comment: It fetches the document

Comment: So, if you're sure that exists you don't have to do that right?

Comment: Depends. The code you linked then uses the content of the document to update a value

Comment: Oh ok I got it thank you so much!